# Use login_hint to pre-fill email box for Google oAuth2

Tags: google-oauth

When getting the access code to use Google api's (oAuth2), one parameter is called login_hint and its defined as;

"When your application knows which user it is trying to authenticate, it may provide this parameter as a hint to the Authentication Server. Passing this hint will either pre-fill the email box on the sign-in form or select the proper multi-login session, thereby simplifying the login flow."

I'm finding it is NOT filling in the email box and wondering why. The url is formed as follows;

```
var url:String = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?' +
    'scope=https://mail.google.com/&' +
    'redirect_uri=<my_redirect_uri>&' +
    'response_type=code&' +
    'login_hint=abc@gmail.com&' +
    'client_id=<my_client_id>;
```

The url works fine to get the login page but the email field is not pre-filled. Can any one tell me how to make this work?

Answer (score 9):

Weird, I tried your url with a client and it worked. Could you verify that `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?redirect_uri=https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground&response_type=code&client_id=407408718192.apps.googleusercontent.com&scope=https://mail.google.com/&login_hint=abc@gmail.com` works for you? Replace abc@gmail.com with an existing email.

Comment: I just tried visiting the URL directly, but it doesn't seem to work for any of the browsers I tested (chrome, FF, IE). Am I missing something or this has since been changed?

Comment: this works! login_hint prefills username which is editable and domain name which is not editable

Answer (score 9):

There is a gotcha here - Google will not prepopulate a fake gmail address. If you put "example@gmail.com" as the parameter it will not work. Just try your real email address and it will work fine though. Took me about an hour to realize this.