# Google oauth2.0 api login_hint not working

Tags: google-authentication

Google OAuth2.0 api login_hint not working. 
I already read [Use login_hint to pre-fill email box for Google oAuth2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16577136/use-login-hint-to-pre-fill-email-box-for-google-oauth2). 
But it does not work.
You can try below link in Chrome or IE. Thanks.

https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=https%3a%2f%2fwww.googleapis.com%2fauth%2fyoutube+https%3a%2f%2fwww.googleapis.com%2fauth%2fyoutube.force-ssl+https%3a%2f%2fwww.googleapis.com%2fauth%2fyoutube.readonly+https%3a%2f%2fwww.googleapis.com%2fauth%2fyoutubepartner+https%3a%2f%2fwww.googleapis.com%2fauth%2fyoutubepartner-channel-audit&redirect_uri=urn%3aietf%3awg%3aoauth%3a2.0%3aoob&response_type=code&client_id=212374846644-1t0rrjglnumal7mgmlupor0dtrrtq8df.apps.googleusercontent.com&login_hint=aabb@test.com

Comment: I think this [answer][ans] might help you.

[ans]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29984015/1385870

Comment: In case that didn't work for you, see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34449994/602146